# Capital letters in field causing query to fail in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have a query which searches for transcripts containing some value.  It should match every document that belongs to a specific tenant.  The query works when its term filter has no capital letters but fails when it does.

Should I encode my tenant ID to a format which uses only lowercase letters?  Or is there a way to make the term filter (or some similar filter) case sensitive?  Or do I need to enable some option on the `tenant_id` field to preserve its case?

```py
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{'match': {'transcript': 'hello, world!'}}],
            'filter': [
                {'term': {'tenant_id': 'XRqtv5O91WEEt'}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `match` instead of `term`:

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{'match': {'transcript': 'hello, world!'}}],
            'filter': [
                {'match': {'tenant_id': 'XRqtv5O91WEEt'}}
                  ^^^^^
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep `term` but use the `keyword` subfield instead (if such a field exists in your mapping)

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{'match': {'transcript': 'hello, world!'}}],
            'filter': [
                {'term': {'tenant_id.keyword': 'XRqtv5O91WEEt'}}
                                    ^^^^^^^^
            ]
        }
    }
}
```